# Shell parameter expansion: how can I get the file name without the directory part?

Tags: shell, makefile, variable-expansion

I was writing a makefile and suppose I have the following;

```
FILES = file1.py \
    folder1/file2.py \
    folder2/file3.py
```

And I have the following for loop:

```
    -@for file in $(FILES); do \
           echo $${file/folder1\/}; \
    done
```

The above will print:

```
file1.py
file2.py
folder2/file3.py
```

The output I want is:

```
file1.py
file2.py
file3.py
```

I've looked at some documentation about shell expansion but couldn't yet find a way to deal with this. May I know how I should change the code to get the correct output? Any help will be very much appreciated.

EDIT: syntax

Comment: Did you forget the backslashes in the `FILES =` lines? Did you forget the semicolon after the echo?

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot to add them in there, but I did write them in the makefile. Sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `echo $${file##*/}`. This will give only the filename part without anything up to the last slash.

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way, may I know where I can find the information related to this? I couldn't find any useful resources online. I don't think I should ask on StackExchange everytime I have a question like this..

Comment: It should be in your sh/ksh/bash/zsh manual under "Parameter Expansion". Note that `make` uses `/bin/sh` and not your login shell to run commands. `/bin/sh` might be a bash in disguise. The POSIX specs for parameter expansion are here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

Answer (score 5):

You've already accepted @Jens's shell-style answer, but I'll suggest a [make-style](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions) solution:

```
-@for file in $(notdir $(FILES)); do \
       echo $${file}; \
done
```